# How can I write a HTML5 regular expression that validates a given word within a string/sentence.

Tags: regex, html

This question is for Regular Expression wizards in Javascript/HTML5.

Basically I'm trying to find a regex that will search for a given word, could be any word in a sentence that someone would type in an input text box.

E.g. Could be "Football" with the string, "I think **Football** is great"

At the moment the closest I can get is this expression

```
(\s|^)+(baloney|darn|drat|fooey|gosh\sdarnit|heck)+(\s|$)
```

Which creates a list of conditions rather than just the one.  I can match one of these words with a space either side of the matched word but anything else is an invalid expression.

What I'd like is to be able to make any sentence valid that contains the word in an expression. I'm beginning to think it's impossible. Anyone know otherwise?

Thanks

Comment: As the answer below says, you actually want to check if your string contains a substring. But I also did a test with regex and doing a simple regex: Football will match the Football inside the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like regex is inappropriate for what you want. I believe you actually want to use String.contains. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcompleacting it. You should just pass in `Football` as the regexp if you want Football to match. If you want to match multiple word then you could do `(baloney|darn|drat|fooey|gosh\sdarnit|heck)` (note that we don't have the (\s|^)+ anymore)

Please be aware that this will match strings that contain `Football` anywhere. For example, `PENGUINFootball` would match.

Is that what you want?

Comment: hi  wdh,

The regex I gave was an example of what I can currently do, match a set of given words. I can either match the word or the word with a space beside it (either side).

But to clarify, that was the only way I could get anything close to what I wanted. I wanted to match a substring within a string, so search for a word and a valid text would be a sentence with that word in it. I think I'm beginning to see though that it isn't really possible with regex and I'm going to have follow what's suggested above to get what I want. It does answer some questions about what regex can do tho. Thnx

Comment: What is it that you do actually want? Have you tried looking at Deadron's answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that I'd made it clear, both in my question and my answer. I've looked and Deardon's link, yes and will look at further but be assured you've all been helpful so far, thanks.  :-)

To clarify again 

Basically I'm trying to search for a string that is inside another string that someone might type in a text box.

E.g. Could be "Football" with the string, "I think Football is great"